# Why is my custom publishing feature not activating?

Tags: feature

I am using Windows 7 64 bit and doing quite a bit of local dev.

Today, I went to create a publishing site or enterprise wiki and I get the following error message:

> Dependency feature with id 89e0306d-453b-4ec5-8d68-42067cdbf98e for feature 'PublishingSite' (id: f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa) is not installed.

I was thinking I had to activate some feature on the web application but that was not it.  The first id is for some navigation feature.  Where/how do I activate this feature?

Comment: i.e. The feature you are trying to activate is dependent on another feature 89e0306d-453b-4ec5-8d68-42067cdbf98e contained in the solution 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 which is not installed.

how do i install this feature?

Comment: That's strange. Do you have this the that feature in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\Navigation?

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer and yes it was the same as Ashish Patel answered above.  I had developed a custom feature called Navigation.  I removed my custom navigation feature.

As such, my custom feature over-wrote the oob navigation feature provided by SharePoint.  The resolution was to copy the navigation directory from one of the servers back to the features directory on my workstation and all is fine now.

Comment: Just pointing out for the benefit of others that in general, changing OOB files will put your SharePoint environment into an unsupported state. Obviously in dev this is okay, because you're never going to call Microsoft to fix your dev environment, but you don't really want to be installing that stuff onto production servers.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to neil's comment, it's always a good practice to start you feature folder names with a unique preamble, i.e. an identifier setting it apart from other (out of the box) features.

Say your project is for client *ClientName* and the project is named *Intranet*, naming your feature folder something like *ClientNameIntranetFeatureName* would be a pretty good way to ensure your feature will never be overwritten / overwrite an out of the box feature.